# parsing input variabele to dataframe filter results in undefined columns selected

Tags: r, function

I used a function which return a data.frame based on the following statement (which work fine!)

```
group <- data.frame(getGroupedData(getTweetTraining(openDBSentiment()))[getGroupedData(getTweetTraining(openDBSentiment()))$Group.2 ==  "test"])
```

The parameter which i want to use(input) for passing it in to the filter of the dataframe cause an error (undefined columns selected ) as result.

```
getBarFrame <- function (input) {
 #Build dataframe from other functions
  group  <-  data.frame(getGroupedData(getTweetTraining(openDBSentiment())))
  #Filter the data.frame based on the input parameter
  group2 <-  group[group$Group.2 ==  input ]
  #select only 2 fields of the data.frame
  group3 <- group2[c("Group.1","sentiment")]
  #return the result tot the function
return (group3)
}
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this

Comment: Turn it into multiple lines, saving intermediary results into different variables and you'll get a good idea what's actually going on and at which step the problem occurs.

Comment: Thanks, LauriK. It works to solve this particulair problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for the question is that you must place the lower , after 
filtering the data.frame.

```
getBarFrame <- function (input) {
 #Build dataframe from other functions
  group  <-  data.frame(getGroupedData(getTweetTraining(openDBSentiment())))
  #Filter the data.frame based on the input parameter
  group2 <-  group[group$Group.2 ==  input , ]
  #select only 2 fields of the data.frame
  group3 <- group2[c("Group.1","sentiment")]
  #return the result tot the function
return (group3)
}
```